# How to override a generic type's log level in serilog

Tags: c#, serilog

I have ASP.NET WebApi application and apgeneric class as follows:

```cs
namespace MyNamespace;

public class MyService<T>
{
    private readonly ILogger<MyService<T>> logger;

    public MyService(ILogger<MyService<T>> logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public void DoWork()
    {
        logger.LogDebug("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

I have tried following configurations in order to override log level inside MyService but without success:

```json
{
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "MyNamespace.MyService": "Debug"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and

```json
{
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "MyNamespace.MyService<>": "Debug"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How do I override log level ONLY for this class?

Comment: Log levels are per category, not type. When you use `Logger<T>`, the type name is used as the category

Comment: So how do I override log level for generic category?

Comment: You missed the point - there's no such thing as a generic category. Log messages are created by concrete loggers. If you don't specify a specific category, the logger's concrete type name is used. Category hierarchies are based on the category name, not the logger that produced the messages.

Comment: In short, if you want to configure log levels for all `MyService<T>` concrete types, you'll have to put `MyService<T>` in a different namespace. Or use `ILoggerFactory.CreateLogger` to create loggers with an explicit category name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logging is configured by logger category, not type. The category is specified when the logger is created using `ILoggerFactory.CreateLogger`, eg :

```
public ContactModel(ILoggerFactory logger)
{
    _logger = logger.CreateLogger("MyCategory");
}
```

Injected loggers use the target type's name as the category. That's not `MyService<T>` but the concrete type `MyService<MyType1>` that's getting constructed.

The easiest way to create a separate category for all `MyService<T>` concrete types is to use a different namespace, eg :

```
namespace MyNamespace.MyServices;

public class MyService<T>
{
...
}
```

The other option is to inject ILoggerFactory and create a logger with an explicit category name:

```
namespace MyNamespace;

public class MyService<T>
{
    private readonly ILogger<MyService<T>> logger;

    public MyService(ILoggerFactory logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger.Create("MyNamespace.MyService");
    }
```

or

```
        this.logger = logger.Create($"MyNamespace.MyService.{typeof(T).Name}");
```

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty close. I have an example where I am overriding the logging level for controller class. My github repo [link](https://github.com/chinmay-trivedi/SeriLogExamples).

> Appsettings.json

```
   { "Serilog": {
      "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.Debug", "Serilog.Sinks.File", "Serilog.Enrichers.Thread", "Serilog.Enrichers.Process", "Serilog.Expressions" ],
      "MinimumLevel": {
        "Override": {
          "SeriLogWebAPI.Controllers" : "Error"
        }
      },
      "WriteTo": [
        {
          "Name": "Console",
          "Args": {
            "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:yyyy:MM:dd hh:mm:ss} {CorrelationId} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"
          }
        }]}}
```

> WeatherForecastController.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace SeriLogWebAPI.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
            "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
        };

        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

        public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _logger.LogInformation("WeatherForecast controller called ");
        }

        [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("WeatherForecast get method Starting.");
            _logger.LogDebug("WeatherForecast get method Starting.");
            _logger.LogWarning("WeatherForecast get method Starting.");
            _logger.LogCritical("WeatherForecast get method Starting.");
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(index)),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }


    }
}
```

This will restrict my logging to anything having `Error` and above loglevel. This is why on my console it is logging only `Fatal/Critical` message but not other lower level logging messages.

[image]

In your case you just need to include namespace of the class. In your `appsettings.json` replace `"MyNamespace.MyService<>"` with `"MyNamespace"`. Something like below:

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "MyNamespace": "Debug"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> Only for a class but not the entire namespace

If you want to override log level only for a class, you need to use `SourceContext`.

```
var myClassLog = Log.ForContext("SourceContext","MyClass");
myClassLog.Information("Hello!");
myClassLog.LogDebug("Hello World!!");
```

> WeatherForecastController.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Serilog;
namespace SeriLogWebAPI.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
            "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
        };

        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;
        private readonly Serilog.ILogger _myLogger = Log.ForContext<WeatherForecastController>();

        public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;            
            _logger.LogInformation("WeatherForecast controller called ");
        }

        [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("WeatherForecast get method Starting.");
            _logger.LogDebug("WeatherForecast get method Starting.");
            _logger.LogWarning("WeatherForecast get method Starting.");
            _logger.LogCritical("WeatherForecast get method Starting.");
            var myClassLogger = _myLogger.ForContext("SourceContext", "MyClass");
            myClassLogger.Information("MyClass Logging is enabled !!!");
            myClassLogger.Debug("MyClass Debug Logging is enabled !!!");
            myClassLogger.Error("MyClass Error Logging is enabled !!!");
            myClassLogger.Fatal("MyClass Fatal Logging is enabled !!!");


            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(index)),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }


    }
}
```

> Appsettings.cs

```
    {
      "Serilog": {
        "MinimumLevel": {
          "Default": "Information",
          "Override": {
            "SeriLogWebAPI.Controllers": "Debug",
            "MyClass": "Error"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

This is how it is logging.

[image]

Comment: I want to override log level for this class only, not whole namespace

Comment: Ok I have updated my answer to show how to override log level for a class only

Comment: I already have tried this. It does not work for generic classes.